# Unable to see any results when benchmarking optaplanner

Tags: java, benchmarking, optaplanner

I am trying to benchmark in Optaplanner, and I am not seeing any results. My directories are all created, however, there are no files and there is no html file for me to view any graphs. Below is an outline of my implementation, can you assist in helping me figure out what I am doing wrong?

I added the following to VehicleRoutingApp.class in main()

```
PlannerBenchmarkFactory plannerBenchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource(
                "org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/benchmark/vehicleRoutingBenchmarkConfig.xml");
        PlannerBenchmark plannerBenchmark = plannerBenchmarkFactory.buildPlannerBenchmark();
        plannerBenchmark.benchmark();
```

The referenced xml looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plannerBenchmark>
    <benchmarkDirectory>local/data/report/vehiclerouting</benchmarkDirectory>
    <parallelBenchmarkCount>AUTO</parallelBenchmarkCount>
    <warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>30</warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>

    <inheritedSolverBenchmark>
        <problemBenchmarks>
            <solutionFileIOClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.persistence.VehicleRoutingFileIO</solutionFileIOClass>
            <!-- Geoffrey datasets -->
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/unsolved/GeoffreyHelpMe.xml</inputSolutionFile>   
            <!-- Belgium datasets -->
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/air/belgium-n50-k10.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/air/belgium-n100-k10.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/air/belgium-n500-k20.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/air/belgium-n1000-k20.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/air/belgium-n2750-k55.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/road-km/belgium-road-km-n50-k10.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/road-km/belgium-road-km-n100-k10.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/road-time/belgium-road-time-n50-k10.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/road-time/belgium-road-time-n100-k10.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <!-- USA datasets -->
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/usa/basic/air/usa-n100-k10.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/usa/basic/air/usa-n500-k20.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/usa/basic/air/usa-n1000-k20.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/usa/basic/air/usa-n5000-k100.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/usa/basic/air/usa-n10000-k100.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/usa/basic/air/usa-n50000-k500.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/usa/basic/air/usa-n100000-k500.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
            ........ <!-- and other datasets that were default -->

            <problemStatisticType>BEST_SCORE</problemStatisticType>
            <!--<problemStatisticType>STEP_SCORE</problemStatisticType>-->
            <!--<problemStatisticType>SCORE_CALCULATION_SPEED</problemStatisticType>-->
            <!--<problemStatisticType>BEST_SOLUTION_MUTATION</problemStatisticType>-->
            <!--<problemStatisticType>MOVE_COUNT_PER_STEP</problemStatisticType>-->
            <!--<problemStatisticType>MEMORY_USE</problemStatisticType>-->
            <!--<singleStatisticType>CONSTRAINT_MATCH_TOTAL_BEST_SCORE</singleStatisticType>-->
            <!--<singleStatisticType>CONSTRAINT_MATCH_TOTAL_STEP_SCORE</singleStatisticType>-->
            <!--<singleStatisticType>PICKED_MOVE_TYPE_BEST_SCORE_DIFF</singleStatisticType>-->
            <!--<singleStatisticType>PICKED_MOVE_TYPE_STEP_SCORE_DIFF</singleStatisticType>-->
        </problemBenchmarks>

        <solver>
            <!--<environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode>-->
            <solutionClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.VehicleRoutingSolution</solutionClass>
            <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Standstill</entityClass>
            <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Customer</entityClass>
            <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.timewindowed.TimeWindowedCustomer</entityClass>

            <scoreDirectorFactory>
                <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT_LONG</scoreDefinitionType>
                <incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.solver.score.VehicleRoutingIncrementalScoreCalculator</incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>
                <!--<scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>-->
                <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
            </scoreDirectorFactory>

            <termination>
                <minutesSpentLimit>5</minutesSpentLimit>
            </termination>
        </solver>
    </inheritedSolverBenchmark>

    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>First Fit</name>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>
    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>First Fit Decreasing</name>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>

    ....... <!-- and other default solverBenchmark tags -->
</plannerBenchmark>
```

The application runs fine. I modeled an xml file called GeoffreyHelpMe.xml, based from the existing cvrptw-25customers.xml example. It looks like the following:

```
<!--
multiple vehicles
25 customers
1 dropoff location
-->
<VrpTimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution id="1">
  <id>0</id>
  <name>C101</name>
  <distanceType>AIR_DISTANCE</distanceType>
  <distanceUnitOfMeasurement>distance</distanceUnitOfMeasurement>
  <locationList id="2">
    <VrpAirLocation id="3">
      <id>0</id>
      <latitude>40.0</latitude>
      <longitude>50.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="4">
      <id>1</id>
      <latitude>45.0</latitude>
      <longitude>68.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="5">
      <id>2</id>
      <latitude>15.0</latitude>
      <longitude>70.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="6">
      <id>3</id>
      <latitude>21.0</latitude>
      <longitude>66.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="7">
      <id>4</id>
      <latitude>42.0</latitude>
      <longitude>68.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="8">
      <id>5</id>
      <latitude>25.0</latitude>
      <longitude>35.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="9">
      <id>6</id>
      <latitude>40.0</latitude>
      <longitude>69.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="10">
      <id>7</id>
      <latitude>40.0</latitude>
      <longitude>66.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="11">
      <id>8</id>
      <latitude>38.0</latitude>
      <longitude>68.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="12">
      <id>9</id>
      <latitude>38.0</latitude>
      <longitude>70.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="13">
      <id>10</id>
      <latitude>35.0</latitude>
      <longitude>66.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="14">
      <id>11</id>
      <latitude>35.0</latitude>
      <longitude>69.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="15">
      <id>12</id>
      <latitude>25.0</latitude>
      <longitude>85.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="16">
      <id>13</id>
      <latitude>22.0</latitude>
      <longitude>75.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="17">
      <id>14</id>
      <latitude>22.0</latitude>
      <longitude>85.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="18">
      <id>15</id>
      <latitude>20.0</latitude>
      <longitude>80.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="19">
      <id>16</id>
      <latitude>20.0</latitude>
      <longitude>85.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="20">
      <id>17</id>
      <latitude>18.0</latitude>
      <longitude>75.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="21">
      <id>18</id>
      <latitude>15.0</latitude>
      <longitude>75.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="22">
      <id>19</id>
      <latitude>15.0</latitude>
      <longitude>80.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="23">
      <id>20</id>
      <latitude>30.0</latitude>
      <longitude>50.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="24">
      <id>21</id>
      <latitude>30.0</latitude>
      <longitude>52.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="25">
      <id>22</id>
      <latitude>28.0</latitude>
      <longitude>52.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="26">
      <id>23</id>
      <latitude>28.0</latitude>
      <longitude>55.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="27">
      <id>24</id>
      <latitude>25.0</latitude>
      <longitude>50.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="28">
      <id>25</id>
      <latitude>25.0</latitude>
      <longitude>52.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
  </locationList>
  <depotList id="29">
    <VrpTimeWindowedDepot id="30">
      <id>0</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="3"/>
      <readyTime>0</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1236000</dueTime>
    </VrpTimeWindowedDepot>
  </depotList>
  <vehicleList id="31">
    <VrpVehicle id="32">
      <id>0</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="33">
      <id>1</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="34">
      <id>2</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="35">
      <id>3</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="36">
      <id>4</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="37">
      <id>5</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="38">
      <id>6</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="39">
      <id>7</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="40">
      <id>8</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="41">
      <id>9</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="42">
      <id>10</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="43">
      <id>11</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="44">
      <id>12</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="45">
      <id>13</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="46">
      <id>14</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="47">
      <id>15</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="48">
      <id>16</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="49">
      <id>17</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="50">
      <id>18</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="51">
      <id>19</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="52">
      <id>20</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="53">
      <id>21</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="54">
      <id>22</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="55">
      <id>23</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="56">
      <id>24</id>
      <capacity>250</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    </VrpVehicle>
  </vehicleList>
  <customerList id="57">
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="58">
      <id>1</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="4"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>9000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1967000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>900000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="59">
      <id>2</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="5"/>
      <demand>30</demand>
      <readyTime>8000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1870000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>900000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="60">
      <id>3</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="6"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>6000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1146000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>900000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="61">
      <id>4</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="7"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>7000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1782000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>900000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="62">
      <id>5</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="8"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>1000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>167000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>900000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="63">
      <id>6</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="9"/>
      <demand>20</demand>
      <readyTime>6000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1702000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="64">
      <id>7</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="10"/>
      <demand>20</demand>
      <readyTime>1000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1225000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="65">
      <id>8</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="11"/>
      <demand>20</demand>
      <readyTime>5000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1324000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="66">
      <id>9</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="12"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>4000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1605000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="67">
      <id>10</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="13"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>7000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1410000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="68">
      <id>11</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="14"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>8000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1505000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="69">
      <id>12</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="15"/>
      <demand>20</demand>
      <readyTime>2000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1721000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="70">
      <id>13</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="16"/>
      <demand>30</demand>
      <readyTime>3000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>192000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="71">
      <id>14</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="17"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>7000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1620000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="72">
      <id>15</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="18"/>
      <demand>40</demand>
      <readyTime>4000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1429000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="73">
      <id>16</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="19"/>
      <demand>40</demand>
      <readyTime>5000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1528000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="74">
      <id>17</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="20"/>
      <demand>20</demand>
      <readyTime>9000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1148000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="75">
      <id>18</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="21"/>
      <demand>20</demand>
      <readyTime>9000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1254000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="76">
      <id>19</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="22"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>8000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1345000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="77">
      <id>20</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="23"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>1000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>173000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="78">
      <id>21</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="24"/>
      <demand>20</demand>
      <readyTime>4000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1965000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="79">
      <id>22</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="25"/>
      <demand>20</demand>
      <readyTime>2000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1083000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="80">
      <id>23</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="26"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>2000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1077000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="81">
      <id>24</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="27"/>
      <demand>10</demand>
      <readyTime>5000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1144000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
    <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="82">
      <id>25</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="28"/>
      <demand>40</demand>
      <readyTime>9000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1024000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>9000</serviceDuration>
    </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
  </customerList>
</VrpTimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution>
```

All I get are folders created, but inside of "sub0" (First Fit > Sub0, for example) is nothing. What am I missing? How to implement Benchmarking?

EDIT
I have ran the application and received feedback saying "compilation completed successfully in 3s 241ms". All I did was run `VehicleRoutingBenchmarkApp.class`.

It did not run too long, I left it alone for 3 hours with the default `vehicleRoutingBenchmarkConfig.xml` file that came with the project. There were no `index.html` files generated. As you can see I have pointed benchmarkDirectory to the following path `local/data/report/vehiclerouting`. As far as the documentation says, this is how I can configure to have the report saved locally. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Has it finished running yet? If you have 2 solverBenchmark elements with 3 inputSolutionFiles with a termination of 5 minutes, it will take 30 minutes to run and another few seconds to generate the index.html. PS: The output solutions themselves won't be saved to disk unless you explicitly configure it (see docs).

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I did not know it takes that long. Let me let it run a while then. I am more confused on my implementation than anything else. Maybe it is working, I will double confirm.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet ok, this has been running for a hour now, and no index file. Is there anything with my setup that you see wrong?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet please see my edited question

Comment: Set the termination time to 5 seconds instead of 5 minutes - turn on info logging for category `org.optaplanner`. That should prove that it isn't stuck.